# Why does including var files using vars_files not work in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to setup a server using Ansible. This is my file structure:

```
group_vars/
  all.yml
  development.yml
  production.yml
  vault/
    all.yml
    development.yml
    production.yml
playbooks/
  development.yml
  production.yml
roles/
  common/
    tasks/
      main.yml
    vars/
      main.yml
ansible.cfg
hosts
```

This is my `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
vault_password_file = ./vault_pass.txt
host_key_checking = False
inventory = ./hosts
```

The `development.yml` playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  name: Development Playbook
  become: true
  roles:
    - ../roles/common
  vars_files:
    - ../group_vars/development.yml
    - ../group_vars/all.yml
    - ../group_vars/vault/development.yml
    - ../group_vars/vault/all.yml
```

And the `tasks/main.yml` file of the `common` role:

```
# Set hostame
- name: Set hostname
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.hostname:
    name: "{{ server.hostname }}"

# Set timezone
- name: Set timezone
  become: true
  community.general.timezone:
    name: "{{ server.timezone }}"

# Update all packages
- name: Update all packages
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    upgrade: dist
    update_cache: true
```

The group_vars/all.yml file looks like this:

```
server:
  hostname: "myhostname"
  timezone: "Europe/Berlin"
```

When running the playbook using ansible-playbook playbooks/development.yml, I get this error:

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'hostname'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'hostname'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml': line 6, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n# Set hostame\n- name: Set hostname\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Can someone explain to me why the `vars_files` does not work and how to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `vars_files` to include files from `group_vars`. Ansible includes files in `group_vars` and `host_vars` automatically based on the active groups and hosts in your play. If you want to include files manually using `vars_files` (or the `include_vars` module), put them somewhere else.

Comment: That's what I assumed, because if I take that `vars_files` part out, then it works. But later in another task I try to access a variable from vault/all.yml. However, that does not work then. How/where do I then import the three files that are in the vault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible automatically imports files and directories in `group_vars` that match the name of an active group. That is, if you are targeting the `production` group, and you have a file `group_vars/production.yaml`, the variables defined in this file will be imported automatically.

If instead of a file you have the directory `group_vars/production/`, then *all files* in that directory will be imported for hosts in the `production` group.

So your files in `group_vars/vault/` will only be imported automatically for hosts in the `vault` hostgroup, which isn't the behavior you want.

Without knowing all the details about your deployment, I would suggest:

- Create directories `group_vars/{all,production/development}`.
- Rename `group_vars/all.yml` inventory files to `group_vars/all/common.yml`, and similarly for `development.yml` and `production.yml` (the name `common.yml` isn't special, you can use whatever name you want).
- Rename `group_vars/vault/all.yml` to `group_vars/all/vault.yaml`, and similarly for the other files.

This will give you the following layout:

```
group_vars/
├── all
│   ├── common.yml
│   └── vault.yml
├── development
│   ├── common.yml
│   └── vault.yml
└── production
    ├── common.yml
    └── vault.yml
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have understood everything so far and have adjusted my file structure accordingly. It now looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/LeoYY4G Unfortunately, I still get the same error as above. Do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: This is my hosts file: https://hastebin.com/uqesimiyil.csharp Might this be a problem? My goal is that depending on the playbook I run, either the variables in the `group_vars/development/` or `group_vars/production/` get import in addition to those in `group_vars/all/`.